# Vue (typescript) Consider renaming the property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button md-menu-trigger>Games</md-button>

      <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item>My Item 1</md-menu-item>
        <md-menu-item>My Item 2</md-menu-item>
      </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>

    <md-menu md-size="medium" md-align-trigger>
      <md-button md-menu-trigger>Align with trigger</md-button>

      <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item>
          <md-button class="md-icon-button">
            <md-icon>home</md-icon>
          </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
      </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .md-menu {
    margin: 24px;
  }
</style>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Component from 'vue-class-component'
  // import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import { mdMenu, mdButton , mdIcon } from 'vue-material'

  const CompProps = Vue.extend({
    props: {
      msg: String
    }
  });

  // Register for components
  @Component({
    components: {
      mdButton,
      mdMenu,
      mdIcon
    }
  })

  @Component
  export default class myHeader extends CompProps {

    // @Prop() msg: string

    helloTimes: number = 0
    test1: string = 'Nikola test'
    sayHello () {
      this.helloTimes++
    }
    greet (): void {
      console.log('Greeting: ' + this.msg)
      // this.$refs.HelloWorld.sayHello()
    }

  }
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

**Error log :**

> vue-class-component.esm.js?2fe1:123 [vue-class-component] Static
> property name 'superOptions' declared on class 'myHeader' conflicts
> with reserved property name of Vue internal. It may cause unexpected
> behavior of the component. Consider renaming the property.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have 2 successive `@Component` instructions?

```
@Component({
 components: {
   mdButton,
   mdMenu, 
   mdIcon
 }
})

@Component
```

Remove the second one and this should work.

Comment: Please give me solution. Is it possible to put it intro class like props...

Comment: I just gave you the solution: remove the second "@Component"